# Retrieve value of reference which points to an object not yet defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm receiving a JSON of objects. Each object could containt a number or a reference to another object in the same JSON which could also be a number or reference etc.

It would look similar to this:

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "value":5
      },
      {
         "value":3
      },
      {
         "value":7
      },
      {
         "reference":1
      }
   ]
}
```

The reference would mean that the value would be the same as `data[reference.value]` in this case `data[1] = 3`. So the hard part is when I receive an object where a reference object points to the object below him. Meaning that it gets undefined when trying to get the value, because I iterate through them as usual. The reference could also point to a non existing object. This is the case that I would need to solve:

```
 {
       "data":[
          {
             "reference":1
          },
          {
             "reference":2
          },
          {
             "reference":3
          },
          {
             "value":10
          }
       ]
    }
```

So could someone give a hint to a possible solution. I'm using React so I could use states here, although I'm not sure how would that look either, it's simple js code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you iterate through list, simpy just use recursion to get value. Something like this

```
const getValue = (item) => {
  if(item.value) return item.value;
  return (getValue(data[item.reference]))
}
const values = data.map(item => getValue(item));
```